# refer to another function by using radio Button

Tags: javascript

I am new with javascript and I have one question now. how can we refer to one function by using Radio button? I have list of countries and this list includes of population and area and density. I want to add radio button to my script when I select for example radio button "area" this function comes back to another function and extract the area of countries from the other function. I have written these functions but it works only for area. I need to add 3 radio button to this script
when I select for example the density button it refers to this function and extract the density of these countries and then the second function will change the colour. please help me

```
var myCantons = []; 
myCantons[0] = ["Name Country","area km²","density",Population];
myCantons[102] = ["Germany",221.90,2696,117];
myCantons[106] = ["Italy",271.50,6510,485];
myCantons[107] = ["Denmark",141.31,2661,406];
myCantons[122] = ["Poland",286.25,3331,237];
myCantons[130] = ["Russia",124.49,5099,431];

 function myInit(){
   for(var i = 100; i < myCantons.length; i++){
    if(typeof myCantons[i] != 'undefined'){
        var myDensity = myCantons[i][2] ;
    var myNewColor = '';
    if(myDensity < 110){
         myNewColor = 'yellow';
         } else if (myDensity > 250){
           myNewColor = 'red';
         } else {
           myNewColor = 'orange';
         }
     var mySvgId ='myCantonId'+(''+i).substr(1);
     document.getElementById(mySvgId).setAttributeNS(null,'fill',myNewColor);
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into DOM events.

```
var handleChange = function (e) {
    if(e.target.checked) {
        // do something if the checkbox was selected
    } else {
        // do something if the checkbox was deselected
    }
}

document.getElementById("myCheckbox").addEventlistener("change", handleChange, false);
```

You can attach a change event to any input element and monitor it's state. For checkboxes/radio buttons that would be the `checked` property. It is true if the input is selected.

Answer (score 0):

We can put three radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="area" value="area" onClick="myInit(this)"/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="density" value="density" onClick="myInit(this)" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="population" value="population" onClick="myInit(this)"/>
```

myInit function would be modified as follows to take argument of radio button object.

```
myInit(myradio)
{

    if(myradio.checked == true && myradio.value=='area')
        //Here logic for returning area will come

    else if(myradio.checked == true && myradio.value=='density')
        //Here logic for returning density will come

    else if(myradio.checked == true && myradio.value=='population')
        //Here logic for returning population will come
}
```